# LAT of an SBox, values are even

Tags: classical-cipher, linear-cryptanalysis, s-boxes

This is probably a silly question, but I could not find any reference. For the [DDT](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/sbox.html#sage.crypto.sbox.SBox.difference_distribution_table) of an SBox, it is easy to see why all the values are even. Is there any related result for [LAT](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/sbox.html#sage.crypto.sbox.SBox.linear_approximation_table) (i.e., all its values are even)?

LAT, for an $n \times n$ SBox, is a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix with row $\alpha$ and column $\beta$ defined as follows:
For all $n$-bit $\alpha$, $\beta$; count how many times $\alpha\cdot x \oplus \beta \cdot y = 0$ holds; and subtract $2^{n-1}$ from it; where $x$ is the vector of input variables, $y$ is the vector of output variables, and $\cdot$ is the dot product.

Answer (score 4):

Let $N(\alpha,\beta)$ be the number of times the equation
$$
\alpha\cdot x \oplus \beta \cdot y=0 \tag{0} \label{0}
$$
holds. Then the LAT matrix entry is
$$
L(\alpha\cdot x \oplus \beta \cdot y )=
N(\alpha\cdot x \oplus \beta \cdot y)-2^{n-1}
$$
and since the second term is even (can prove $n=1$ case directly) we need to show that $N(\alpha\cdot x \oplus \beta \cdot y)$ is even.

The basic idea is that the set of vectors over $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ of the form
$$a\cdot x=c \tag{1} \label{1} $$ has even cardinality
for any constant $c\in \mathbb{F}_2.$ Observe that this applied to $\alpha\cdot x$ and $\beta\cdot y$ means that $N(\alpha,\beta)$ is also even if we can prove $\eqref{1}$.

To prove $\eqref{1}$ assume $a\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^n,$ since if $a=0,$ the relation holds for all $x\in \mathbb{F}_2^n,$ i.e., for $2^n$ vectors.

If $a\neq 0,$ let $w$ be the Hamming weight of $a$ and let $s_a$ be the support of $a,$ i.e., $s_a=\{i: 1\leq i\leq n, a_i=1\}$. Then, the inner product $a\cdot x$ is invariant when the components $a_i$ in the complement of the support take on all possible $2^n-2^w$ values, since they don't feature in the inner product. Clearly $2^n-2^w$ is even.

Finally note that equation $\eqref{0}$ holds if and only if $\alpha\cdot x$ and $\beta\cdot y$ are both equal to the same constant $c$. So it holds an even number of times.

**Remark:** This argument also works for an arbitrary $n\times m$ S-box $S:\mathbb{F}_2^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2^m$ for any $m\geq 1$.

Comment: " (can prove $n=0$ case directly)" -- sorry, don't get it. $n$ is the size of the SBox, so $n=0$ does not mean anything!

Comment: fixed! it should be $n=1$